# Does an Eldritch Knight fighter's Weapon-Bonded net free a restrained creature when summoned?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, weapons, conditions, eldritch-knight

The [Eldritch Knight fighter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#EldritchKnight)'s [Weapon Bond](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/fighter#WeaponBond-221) feature (PHB, p. 75) says:

> At 3rd level, you learn a ritual that creates a magical bond between yourself and one weapon. [...] If it is on the same plane of existence, you can summon that weapon as a bonus action on your turn, causing it to teleport instantly to your hand.

Edward the Eldritch Knight has a Weapon Bond with a net.

Edward's net has restrained a goblin. 
Edward has walked some distance away from the goblin.

What happens when Edward summons his net; is the goblin freed, or does the net arrive with the goblin still in it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## The goblin is freed.

Here's the relevant rules for the net:

> A Large or smaller creature hit by a net is restrained **until it is freed**. A creature can use its action to make a DC 10 Strength check, freeing itself or another creature within its reach on a success. Dealing 5 slashing damage to the net (AC 10) also frees the creature without harming it, ending the effect and destroying the net.

Note that the rules do not list all of the ways that a creature can be freed; for example, it doesn't mention another creature just removing the net when out of combat, or the restrained creature teleporting away. The rules use 'freed' in its usual sense as the general rule, and then lists a couple of specifics that can apply in some circumstances. Having the net disappear (via Weapon Bond) clearly also frees the goblin.

Comment: The alternative possibility is that the net arrives with the goblin still in it. What reason is there to prefer this reading over that one?

Comment: @MarkWells Because Weapon Bond summons "that weapon", not "that weapon and and anything connected to it, entangled with it, contained by it, etc". This reading just asks the simple hypothetical: "if the net were no longer there, would the goblin be freed?". Weapon Bond explicitly takes care of the "net no longer there" part.